# Laravel 5.6 route is not working, Sorry, the page you are looking for cannot be found

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel 5.6. My route articles/create is sent to controller ArticleController@create method where I need to get view create.blade.php, but I am receving: **Sorry, the page you are looking for cannot be found.** If I change route to article/create or anything else instead of articles/create it will work fine and I will get my view. But only route name articles/create is not working and receiving that error.

This is my route in web.php:
[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLDMn.png)

This is ArticleController@create method:
[ArticleController@create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXArF.png)

Here is my view in laravel application:
[resources/views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqxE4.png)

Comment: Do you see the route when you run the following on the command line `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Thanks for help, I have found the answer, in my web.php file I have route articles/{id} above articles/create, and this route have been hit. I have changed the order of those two routes and now it's working fine.

Comment: Don't use pictures to display code. It's much easier for us to just see the code in here.